# How to add table view dynamically by parsing json data

Tags: android, json, tableview

I am calling a function into a thread and , put these objects to tableView but I am taking illegal state exception.I couldn't solve why? Here is my code responsible for calling the function :

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                            fillTable(jArray);

                                    }
                               });
```

And the function is :

```
private void fillTable(JSONArray jArray){

    TextView t1v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
    TextView t2v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
    TextView t3v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
    TextView t4v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
    TextView t5v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
    TextView t6v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
    ArrayList<JSONObject> listdata = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();     
    for(int i = 0 ; i < jArray.length() ; i++)
    {
        listdata.add(jArray.optJSONObject(i));

    }
    int i = jArray.length()-1;

    while( i >= 0 )
    {
        try {
            json_data = listdata.get(i);
            //json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(ReportAllActivity.this);
            t1v.setText(json_data.getString("heat"));
            t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t1v);

            t2v.setText(json_data.getString("oc_count"));
            t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t2v);

            t3v.setText(json_data.getString("who"));
            t3v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t3v);

            t4v.setText(json_data.getString("alarm"));
            t4v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t4v);


            t5v.setText(json_data.getString("do_duration"));
            t5v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t5v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t5v);


            t6v.setText(json_data.getString("input_time"));
            t6v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t6v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            tbrow.addView(t6v);
            listdata.remove(i);
            i--;
            reportTable.addView(tbrow);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  



    }
}
```

and my LogCat file :

```
    09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1970)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1822) 
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1802)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.example.hsvarge.ReportAllActivity.fillTable(ReportAllActivity.java:263)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.example.hsvarge.ReportAllActivity.access$1(ReportAllActivity.java:192)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.example.hsvarge.ReportAllActivity$3$1.run(ReportAllActivity.java:170)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-07 16:28:57.142: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve this problem?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appeared because of using same TextView everywhere.

`tbrow.addView(t1v);`

You are adding this view on every iteration. But it should be different views.
You should create different TextView on every iteration of you algorithm.

Comment: If ı made this creation on every creation,thhe program is giving OutOfMemory exception because there are too much data.How can I handle this?

Comment: You should somehow try to optimize your program memory managment. 
First you should try inflate your TextView from xml file.
Something like this:
`View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_lv_events, null);`

If programm still failes maybe you should show user only part of your interface(half off all views).

I think you should ask new question.